# Quantum phase estimation error on most likely phase

Tags: quantum-phase-estimation

I have found an error formula for quantum phase estimation in terms of the total number of qubits, $t$, necessary to to measure the closest phase to an accuracy of $n$ bits with a probability of at least $1-\epsilon$,
$$
t \geq n + \log(2 + \frac{1}{2\epsilon})
$$
from [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.10430) which cites N&C.  However, what if instead I fix the result register size to some number of qubits, $n$, with complete disregard for the probability to measure the phase in one go, and instead take 1024 shots of my circuit.  I will get a distribution of phases (unless it is an exact value).  What is the error on my most likely phase?  That is, is there an error bar on my most likely measured phase, or a confidence band I can deduce from $n$ and my shots alone?